# What is the function of if __name__ == '__main__'?

Tags: python

If I execute the codes below without  if **name** == '**main**', nothing is printed on the screen.
That is, if **name** == '**main**' seems to be essential.
What is the function of if **name** == '**main**'?

```
# if __name__ =='__main__':
       # main()
```

```
def input_celsius_value():
    value = float(input("input celsius for converting it to fahrenheit : "))
    return value

def convert_celsius_fahrenheit(celsius_value):
    fahrenheit_value = ((9/5)*celsius_value)+32
    return fahrenheit_value

def print_fahrenheit_value(celsius_value, fahrenheit_value) :
    print("celsius temperature : %f" %celsius_value)
    print("fahrenheit temperature : %f" %fahrenheit_value)

def main():
    print("This program converts celsius to fahrenheit")
    print("============================")
    celsius_value = input_celsius_value()
    fahrenheit_value = convert_celsius_fahrenheit(celsius_value)
    print_fahrenheit_value(celsius_value, fahrenheit_value)
    print("===========================")
    print("This program ended")


if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does if \_\_name\_\_ == "\_\_main\_\_": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: Here is a good video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sugvnHA7ElY

Answer (score 0):

Without those 2 lines of code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
```

there is no function called, you just define 4 functions so nothing is executed. When the interpreter runs a source file it runs all the code in it. Even just having `main()` without `if __name__ == '__main__':` will still execute your function. `__name__` is just a special variable that gets populated depending on what is being executed (the name of the class/function/method etc). When you run a new file, the interpreter initializes it to `'__main__'` and you can use that as an entry point for your program.

Comment: I can't understand this sentence. Can you elaborate more on it?      __name__ is just a special variable that gets populated depending on what is being executed (the name of the class/function/method etc)

Comment: Python has some special variables. When your script is runing the variable `__name__` always holds the name of the class/function/.. executed. At first this is initialized with `'__main__'`.